# How to extract valid urls of similar pattern?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping an entire article management system storing thousands of articles. My script works, but the problem is that `beautifulsoup` and `requests` both take a long in determining whether the the page is an actual article or an article not found page. I have approximately 4000 articles and by calculating, the amount time the script will run will complete is in days.

```
for article_url in edit_article_list:
    article_edit_page = s.get(article_url, data=payload).text
    article_edit_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_edit_page, 'lxml')

    # Section
    if article_edit_soup.find("select", {"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fvArticle$ddlSubMenu"}) == None:
        continue
    else:
        for thing in article_edit_soup.find("select", {"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fvArticle$ddlSubMenu"}).findAll("option", {"selected":"selected"}):
            f.write(thing.get_text(strip=True) + "\t")
```

The first `if` determines whether the url is good or bad.
`edit_article_list` is made by:

```
for count in range(87418,307725):
    edit_article_list.append(login_url+"AddEditArticle.aspxArticleID="+str(count))
```

My script right now checks for the bad and good urls and then scrapes the content. Is there any way I can get the valid urls of similar pattern using `requests` while making the url list?

Comment: So your `edit_article_list` is complete and correct? How long does it take for each page on average to parrse?

Comment: @JonClements The problem is that in between range 87418 to 307725 there are some numbers missing. For example , maybe 90000 to 10000 is missing

Comment: no `edit_article_list` is more than complete. It contains bad urls too. It takes about 5 seconds to parse one page. But when I try to parse using a list of all articles, it takes alot of time

Comment: So, if your system returns a 404 to tell you it doesn't exist, then just continue to the next one? (or if you know a range doesn't exist, then skip it)... Can't quite see what the issue is here?

Comment: Should I post my entire code if anybody is wondering.

Comment: @JonClements I said it at the beginning that the script works just fine but the problem is it takes alot of time(in days).

Comment: Does the system return 404 on no article found? And do those also take about 5 seconds?

Comment: Remove the parsing logic and just loop through each url and do the request to get it. Also assign `s.get(article_url, data=payload)` to a variable and see what `.status_code` is for missing articles (that way can actually skip them properly like Jon is telling you). That should tell you if its slow parsing or it's because of all the requests.

Comment: Also you say you have 4000 articles but are searching over 200,000 urls - that's a lot of requests not going anywhere. Is there a page you can go to with the list or articles to try and parse out the actual article numbers directly?

Comment: @KenSyme Yes, there is but it is paginated. So that's the same thing.

Comment: It will be a lot faster scraping links for the articles from that page and moving through the paginated pages until the end than it will be looping over 200,000 urls hoping for 4,000 hits. Can either find the page number in the URL and increment, scarping each page for article links, then using the above to scrape the articles themselves.  Or can find the "next page" links and go to that url each time, until it doesn't exist.

Comment: @KenSyme Okay I'll give it a try.

Comment: @KenSyme And one more thing you told me to use `.status_code` and check the response, but when I print them they are all `200`. This is because I am redirected to another page. Do you have any other method similar to this. This is way faster than before.

Comment: It depends how that 200 is coming about - is it replacing the page or is it redirecting. Could try `r = requests.get(article_url, data=payload, allow_redirects=False)` and see if you get a 30x status code. If you go to a url for an article that doesn't exist in the browser, where do you end up? Does the url change?

Comment: @KenSyme yes, If an article Id is wrong, it redirects me to http://katytrailweekly.com/genericerror.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Admin/AddEditArticle.aspx, and I tried `allow_redirects=False` and now all the responses are `302`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159382/discussion-between-ken-syme-and-irfan-sindhi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip articles which don't exist, need to not allow redirects and check the status code:

```
for article_url in edit_article_list:
    r = requests.get(article_url, data=payload, allow_redirects=False)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        continue
    article_edit_page = r.text
    article_edit_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_edit_page, 'lxml')

    # Section
    if article_edit_soup.find("select", {"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fvArticle$ddlSubMenu"}) == None:
        continue
    else:
        for thing in article_edit_soup.find("select", {"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fvArticle$ddlSubMenu"}).findAll("option", {"selected":"selected"}):
            f.write(thing.get_text(strip=True) + "\t")
```

I do though recommend parsing the article list page for the actual urls - you are currently firing off over 200,000 requests and only expecting 4,000 articles, that is a lot of overhead and traffic, and not very efficient!